# Installing privacy fence - hung panel 45 degree corner

Tags: fence

I am planning a hung panel fence. My intent was to rip a 4x4 at a 45 and mate it to the interior face of each end post. This corner is to allow for easement clearance for an electrical pole that sits at the corner of the property line. 
The 45 would save me the time and effort of an extra post were I to invert the corner and turn the full 90 degrees.

Is there a better solution that I’m not thinking of?

Comment: Welcome to [diy.se]! It might help to include a link to the "other related question", and including some drawings (even a rough, but well labeled pencil sketch) will help people envision exactly what you're after.

Comment: Is there a reason you _want_ a better solution? What about this strategy doesn't appeal to you? The question is rather vague. Also, there's probably no reason you can't fit your panel to the posts without adding angles to the post, assuming they're long enough.

Comment: I am not understanding the geometry of your plan and why/how angled braces are used/needed. ?

Comment: Nothing about it is unappealing really, just making sure there wasn’t a better easier way I wasn’t thinking of or a piece of hardware I was unaware of.